# WebPack TypeError: Cannot read property 'request' of undefined

Tags: angular, npm, webpack

I've inherited an existing Angular2 project. When I run `NPM start` I get a long error beginning with:

> Html Webpack Plugin:
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'request' of undefined
> ...

Full error output: http://textuploader.com/d5n25

Any ideas what this means and how I can debug this to find out the file/line of code that is the problem?

Also on Windows 8.1 if that information helps.

Comment: Did you type webpack first?

Comment: What node and npm versions a used? Similar problem appeared here: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1922

Comment: Did u get the solution ? I am getting same error.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. Mine came from multiple versions of both webpack and HTML Webpack Plugin.

Check with `npm ls webpack html-webpack-plugin` whether you are having version conflicts and remove the one you don't need.

Comment: Cool, I also met the same issue and solved it by updating `webpack` and `html-webpack-plugin` to the latest version.