# TypeError: Cannot read property 'request' of undefined with angular-cli

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli, webpack-dev-server

I am using `webpack` in my `angular 2` project. It is working fine with `npm` but after installing `npm install -g angular-cli` when I use `ng' command to create component or to build then it is showing below error.

> ERROR in   TypeError: Cannot read property 'request' of undefined
>
> - ExternalModuleFactoryPlugin.js:37 handleExternals
>     [BackofficeVidapayCRM]/[webpack]/lib/ExternalModuleFactoryPlugin.js:37:33
> - ExternalModuleFactoryPlugin.js:46 next
>     [BackofficeVidapayCRM]/[webpack]/lib/ExternalModuleFactoryPlugin.js:46:8
> - ExternalModuleFactoryPlugin.js:59 handleExternals
>     [BackofficeVidapayCRM]/[webpack]/lib/ExternalModuleFactoryPlugin.js:59:7
> - ExternalModuleFactoryPlugin.js:79 ExternalModuleFactoryPlugin.
>     [BackofficeVidapayCRM]/[webpack]/lib/ExternalModuleFactoryPlugin.js:79:5
> - NormalModuleFactory.js:207
>     [BackofficeVidapayCRM]/[angular-cli]/[webpack]/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:20
>     7:3
> - Tapable.js:168
>     [BackofficeVidapayCRM]/[tapable]/lib/Tapable.js:168:11
> - NormalModuleReplacementPlugin.js:26 NormalModuleFactory.
>     [BackofficeVidapayCRM]/[angular-cli]/[webpack]/lib/NormalModuleReplacementPl
>     ugin.js:26:11
> - Tapable.js:172 NormalModuleFactory.applyPluginsAsyncWaterfall
>     [BackofficeVidapayCRM]/[tapable]/lib/Tapable.js:172:13
> - NormalModuleFactory.js:191 NormalModuleFactory.create
>     [BackofficeVidapayCRM]/[angular-cli]/[webpack]/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:19
>     1:8
> - Compilation.js:359 Compilation.process [as _addModuleChain]
>     [BackofficeVidapayCRM]/[angular-cli]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:359:16
> - Compilation.js:435 Compilation.process [as addEntry]
>     [BackofficeVidapayCRM]/[angular-cli]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:435:7
> - SingleEntryPlugin.js:22 SingleEntryPlugin.
>     [BackofficeVidapayCRM]/[webpack]/lib/SingleEntryPlugin.js:22:15
> - Tapable.js:193 Compiler.applyPluginsParallel
>     [BackofficeVidapayCRM]/[tapable]/lib/Tapable.js:193:14
> - Compiler.js:463 Compiler.
>     [BackofficeVidapayCRM]/[angular-cli]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:463:8
> - Tapable.js:95 Compiler.applyPluginsAsyncSeries
>     [BackofficeVidapayCRM]/[tapable]/lib/Tapable.js:95:46
> - Compiler.js:456 Compiler.compile
>     [BackofficeVidapayCRM]/[angular-cli]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:456:7
> - Compiler.js:265 Compiler.runAsChild
>     [BackofficeVidapayCRM]/[angular-cli]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:265:7
> - compiler.js:70
>     [BackofficeVidapayCRM]/[html-webpack-plugin]/lib/compiler.js:70:19
> - debuggability.js:299 Promise._execute
>     [BackofficeVidapayCRM]/[bluebird]/js/release/debuggability.js:299:9
> - promise.js:481 Promise._resolveFromExecutor
>     [BackofficeVidapayCRM]/[bluebird]/js/release/promise.js:481:18
> - promise.js:77 new Promise
>     [BackofficeVidapayCRM]/[bluebird]/js/release/promise.js:77:14
> - compiler.js:69 Object.compileTemplate
>     [BackofficeVidapayCRM]/[html-webpack-plugin]/lib/compiler.js:69:10
> - index.js:47 Compiler.
>     [BackofficeVidapayCRM]/[html-webpack-plugin]/index.js:47:40
> - Tapable.js:193 Compiler.applyPluginsParallel
>     [BackofficeVidapayCRM]/[tapable]/lib/Tapable.js:193:14
> - Compiler.js:463 Compiler.
>     [BackofficeVidapayCRM]/[angular-cli]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:463:8
> - Tapable.js:95 Compiler.applyPluginsAsyncSeries
>     [BackofficeVidapayCRM]/[tapable]/lib/Tapable.js:95:46
> - Compiler.js:456 Compiler.compile
>     [BackofficeVidapayCRM]/[angular-cli]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:456:7
> - Compiler.js:219 Compiler.
>     [BackofficeVidapayCRM]/[angular-cli]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:219:10
> - Compiler.js:367 Compiler.readRecords
>     [BackofficeVidapayCRM]/[angular-cli]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:367:10
> - Compiler.js:216 Compiler.
>     [BackofficeVidapayCRM]/[angular-cli]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:216:9
> - Tapable.js:102 next
>     [BackofficeVidapayCRM]/[tapable]/lib/Tapable.js:102:11
> - CachePlugin.js:34 Compiler.
>     [BackofficeVidapayCRM]/[angular-cli]/[webpack]/lib/CachePlugin.js:34:58
> - Tapable.js:106 Compiler.applyPluginsAsyncSeries
>     [BackofficeVidapayCRM]/[tapable]/lib/Tapable.js:106:13
> - Compiler.js:213 Compiler.
>     [BackofficeVidapayCRM]/[angular-cli]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:213:8
> - Tapable.js:102 next
>     [BackofficeVidapayCRM]/[tapable]/lib/Tapable.js:102:11
> - NodeEnvironmentPlugin.js:23 Compiler.
>     [BackofficeVidapayCRM]/[angular-cli]/[webpack]/lib/node/NodeEnvironmentPlugi
>     n.js:23:3
> - Tapable.js:106 Compiler.applyPluginsAsyncSeries
>     [BackofficeVidapayCRM]/[tapable]/lib/Tapable.js:106:13
> - Compiler.js:210 Compiler.run
>     [BackofficeVidapayCRM]/[angular-cli]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:210:7
> - build-webpack.js:21
>     [BackofficeVidapayCRM]/[angular-cli]/tasks/build-webpack.js:21:29
> - build-webpack.js:20 Class.run
>     [BackofficeVidapayCRM]/[angular-cli]/tasks/build-webpack.js:20:16
> - build.js:54 Class.run
>     [BackofficeVidapayCRM]/[angular-cli]/commands/build.js:54:26
> - command.js:152 Class.
>     [BackofficeVidapayCRM]/[angular-cli]/angular-cli/lib/models/command.js:152:17
> - next_tick.js:103 process._tickCallback
>     internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7

**package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "starter",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "angular-cli": { },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ng serve \"npm run server\"",
    "lint": "tslint \"src/**/*.ts\"",
    "test": "ng test",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update",
    "e2e": "protractor",
    "typings-install": "typings install",
    "postinstall": "npm run typings-install",
    "build": "webpack --inline --colors --progress --display-error-details --display-cached",
    "server": "webpack-dev-server --inline --colors --progress --display-error-details --display-cached --port 3000  --content-base src"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.2.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.2.3",
    "@angular/core": "2.2.3",
    "@angular/forms": "2.2.3",
    "@angular/http": "2.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.2.3",
    "@angular/router": "3.2.3",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.23",
    "angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.20",
    "animate.css": "3.1.1",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "font-awesome": "^4.6.1",
    "ie-shim": "^0.1.0",
    "jquery": "^3.1.0",
    "metismenu": "^2.5.0",
    "pace": "0.0.4",
    "pace-progress": "^1.0.2",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "systemjs": "0.19.27"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "2.2.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.42",
    "angular-cli": "1.0.0-beta.22-1",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0-beta.1",
    "jasmine-core": "2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "2.5.0",
    "karma": "1.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.2.1",
    "protractor": "4.0.9",
    "ts-node": "1.2.1",
    "tslint": "^4.0.2",
    "typescript": "~2.0.3",
    "webdriver-manager": "10.2.5",
    "angular2-template-loader": "^0.6.0",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^3.0.0-beta.13",
    "bootstrap-webpack": "0.0.5",
    "css-loader": "^0.26.1",
    "exports-loader": "^0.6.3",
    "expose-loader": "^0.7.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.1",
    "file-loader": "^0.9.0",
    "imports-loader": "^0.7.0",
    "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "to-string-loader": "^1.1.5",
    "typings": "^2.0.0",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "webpack": "^1.14.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.16.2",
    "webpack-merge": "^1.1.1"
  }
}
```

Please help me to solve this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WebPack TypeError: Cannot read property 'request' of undefined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40752594/webpack-typeerror-cannot-read-property-request-of-undefined)

Answer (score 1):

You can check on package.json on your path to see if your version of your webpack is too low,I just update my webpack version to 2.x,and try 'npm install webpack --save-dev'again, it works