# Error "Cannot read property 'request' of undefined" in Angular 2+ Project

Tags: javascript, angular, google-drive-api, google-api-js-client

I'm writing code to upload a text file in Google drive using **gapi**. I tried using below code.

```
  var createTxtFile = function(name,text,parentId,token) {
    console.log("Inside  Code ");
    var auth_token = token;
    const boundary = '-------314159265358979323846';
    const delimiter = "\r\n--" + boundary + "\r\n";
    const close_delim = "\r\n--" + boundary + "--";
    const mimeType = 'text/plain';
    var contentType = text.type || 'application/octet-stream';
    var metadata = { 
      "name" : name,
      "mimeType": mimeType,
      "parents": [parentId]
    };  

    var multipartRequestBody =
        delimiter +
        'Content-Type: application/json\r\n\r\n' +
        JSON.stringify(metadata) +
        delimiter +
        'Content-Type: ' + contentType + '\r\n' +
        'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n' +
        '\r\n' +
        close_delim;
    console.log("After multipartRequestBody ;");
    var request = gapi.client.request({ 
        'path': '/upload/drive/v3/files/',
        'method': 'POST',
        'params': {'uploadType': 'multipart'},
        'headers': { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/mixed; boundary="' + boundary + '"', 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + auth_token },
        'body': multipartRequestBody 
    });
    request.execute(function(file) { 
        console.log(file);
        console.log("Wrote to file " + file.name + " id: " + file.id); 
    });
}
```

But, When I click on submit button it works fine until the console log **"After multipartRequestBody ;"**. Then after I get the below error

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'request' of undefined
    at createTxtFile (VM5498 main.js:848)
    at ProfileComponent.push../src/app/profile/profile.component.ts.ProfileComponent.downloadcsv (VM5498 main.js:860)
    at VM5498 main.js:747
```

I tried to updating **"html-webpack-plugin"** but no luck.

Comment: Based from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40752594/webpack-typeerror-cannot-read-property-request-of-undefined), the issue might be from multiple versions of both webpack and HTML Webpack Plugin. As suggested, check with `npm ls webpack html-webpack-plugin` whether you are having version conflicts and remove the one you don't need.

Comment: I tried that link but Does webpack and html-webpack-plugin both should have same versions?

Comment: ├─┬ @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.8.6
│ ├── html-webpack-plugin@3.2.0
│ └── webpack@4.23.1  deduped
└── webpack@4.23.1

Comment: It returned me above output ... Which versions are conflicting here?